# Procedure with refcursor .refcursor should be out parameter

Tags: plsql

Please help me writing a program procedure with refcursor. Refcursor should be out parameter.

If i give input deptno it shows employee details in that department,also write unit testing block :

I tried like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE poph (i IN NUMBER, p OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
   OPEN p FOR 'select * from emp where deptno=' || i;

   FOR i IN p
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (i.ename || '**' || i.JOB);
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE p;
END;
/
```

///////unit testing/////

```
DECLARE
   M   NUMBER := '&n';
   n   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   poph (M, n);
END;
```

Comment: Do you want us to do the whole homework for you? Please make an attempt to solve the problem yourself and if you face any issue please post the question. Meanwhile you can also have a look at the [Help Section](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE poph(i IN NUMBER,p out sys_refcursor)
IS
BEGIN
OPEN p FOR 'select * from emp where deptno='||i;
FOR i IN p loop
dbms_output.put_line(i.ename||'**'||i.JOB);
END loop;
CLOSE p;
end;

////////unit testing/////
DECLARE
m NUMBER:='&n';
n sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
poph(m,n);
END;

Comment: cant use for loop in refcursor....plz gv solution

Answer (score 0):

You are making 2 mistakes.

1) Openin a refcursor for dynamic select statement which will not work without execute immediate statement.

> OPEN p FOR 'select * from emp where deptno=' || i;

2) Looping through a ref cursor which is not valid;

> FOR i IN p

Do it this way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE poph (i IN NUMBER, p OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS

v_sql varchar2(100);
BEGIN
   v_sql := 'select employee_id,salary from employee where employee_id=' || i;

   execute immediate v_sql;

   OPEN p FOR v_sql;

END;
/
```

///////unit testing/////

```
DECLARE
   M          NUMBER := '&n';
   n          SYS_REFCURSOR;
   v_emp_id   NUMBER;
   v_sal      NUMBER;
BEGIN
   poph (M, n);

   LOOP
      FETCH n INTO v_emp_id, v_sal;

      EXIT WHEN n%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_emp_id);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: thnks xing happy